# Trying to add employee numbers to Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am tryign to add employee numbers to all of my AD users by importing a csv file with first name, last name, employee number and email fields.

The issue I am having is that I have come across some users that the first name in the csv file does not match up to the first name in AD.

I have searched for weeks on trying to figure out how to get powershell to search ad using the last name and only the first letter of the first name field from the csv, but I juat cannot figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
ForEach ($User in (Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\mike.mullen\Desktop\Active Users with Email.csv'))
{
$Last = $User.LastName
$First = $User.FirstName
$EmployeeNumber = $User.EmployeeId
Get-ADUser -Filter '(Surname -eq $Last) -and (GivenName -like $First)' |
Set-ADObject -Replace @{EmployeeNumber="$EmployeeNumber"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to construct a filter that searches for first names with a specific prefix (ie. the first letter from the first name from the CSV), you'll need to:

1. Grab the first character from `$First`
2. Append a wildcard `*` character to it:

The first step can be accomplished with the [`String.Substring()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
$Surname = $User.LastName
$FirstLetter = $User.FirstName.Substring(0,1) + '*'
Get-ADUser -Filter '(Surname -eq $Surname) -and (GivenName -like $FirstLetter)'
```

Comment: That is working, unfortunately that is not the only mis-information in our AD environment. But using that and email search, I thing I can get most of the users taken care of. Thanks alot Mathias!

Comment: @MikeMullen You're most welcome :) Feel free to ask another question if you're struggling with anything else